# Easiest way to automatically update Twitter & Facebook when I update a wordpress blog

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter

I'm running a self-hosted version of wordpress, so plugins are an option that is available. I'm wondering what the best way to have my Twitter and Facebook accounts automatically update whenever I add a new post to my blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had great luck with [Twitter Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/) for updating Twitter, and Networked Blogs (search on Facebook) for Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

ifttt.com is a plug-in free method which can do this!

Comment: Notable is that at present (2016) it apparently only allows posting to one Facebook page, so to set up mirror posting for two Twitter feeds (I don't use Twitter, I want those on Facebook) I need 2 IFTTT accounts.

Answer (score 1):

**Facebook Connect** WordPress Plugin (compatible with WP 3.0) is very strong. Here's a list of features from the website.

```
* Open Graph Social Plugins (New!), like, activity and recommendations
* Build a community
* Login using your Facebook account
* Send comments to Facebook profile feed
* Invite your friends to the blog community
* See last visitors
* Facebook share counter
* Facebook fan page widget
* Facebook comments box
* Facebook user email store
```

**Post to Twitter** is a highly rated plugin to send out a tweet every time you post on your blog, and vice versa, depending on configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Search the [plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) for [Twitter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=twitter&sort=) and for [Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=Facebook&sort=) and you will find that others have already created plugins which do just what you are looking for.

Comment: LMGYFY is rarely a good answer. AFIK there is only _one_ such Facebook App and it isn't too great.